What is the next step after login for frontend? I am working with .NET 8 Blazor Web App InteractiveAuto
I am working on the Frontend of a Project and I am using the latest Blazor Web App InteractiveAuto after using InteractiveServer caused me a problem. To begin with, I created a login page, that take a user's username, password and a few other parameters and make a login request via api call '/auth/signin' to the backend which is being developed by our backend developer. Presumably, he did the authentication and send me back with a Set-Cookie. Okay, here is when the problem start.
Problem
Because I initially used Blazor Web App InteractiveServer, I came to knew that all the request are made using signalr and not the browser, and because of that even after receiving his Set-Cookie, the cookie isn't displayed on the application tab of the developer's tools. Which leaves me with no other choice but to use HttpContextAccessor and manually extract the cookie and store it in a class, and add in into every subsequent request I make to the backend. Here is where I start to not understand what should be the next step.
Because according to my backend developer, I need to authenticate the user based on the presence of cookie, and once the user is authenticated, he can access an [Authorize] tagged page. I tried a few times but failed to implement this because the manual method of extracting the cookie is returning cookie = null even after I received the Set-Cookie and even after the cookie are included in subsequent headers. Maybe my method was wrong, I'm not sure. Which brings me to another method, that is to try and use InteractiveAuto instead.
InteractiveAuto

Now, when I work with InteractiveAuto method, I created the Login.razor page on the client side components, and included the AuthenticationService class for making login request there too. That way, I can let the browser to make the request and after successful request, I get the Set-Cookie.

The browser also stores the Cookie in the application tab and automatically add it into subsequent request.

Here is where I stuck again, as per told by my Backend Developer, I need to authenticate the user after getting the Set-Cookie and before navigating the authenticated user to the homepage tagged [Authorize]. So yeah. I tried authenticating again.

First method, I use JavaScript to check for presence of cookie on the browser and consider a user authenticated, but it didn't work.

Second method, is I make another call to the backend this time the call is '/verify_session'. and in return, the backend sends me a success code 200. when I get the success code, consider the user authenticated. I tried this method, and debug, I managed to get the user is authenticated, but still when I try to navigate the user to a tagged [Authorize] page, it still failed.


Realization Maybe
I tried so many different methods to authenticate user and navigate him to an authorize page. And still failed. Which makes me think, am I doing the right procedure here? Is authenticating a user my job or is it already done by the backend when I make the login request and he sends me back a Set-Cookie. What is actually the next step that I, as a Frontend dev need to do after getting the Set-Cookie from him? Is it User-session, is it state management, is it really authenticating and authorize, or is it something else?
I am looking to ensure that my approach is secure and follows best practices for a production environment.

[Polite] If "InteractiveServer caused me a problem" then jumping straight into trying to code an InteractiveAuto application as your first application is going to cause you a lot more problems.  You need to go and find some online tutorials on authentication and gain some knowledge.  My guess is you need a custom AuthenticationStateProvider.

Okay, so apparently, I managed to pass the authentication and authorization phase. here. Im not sure if it's the right way or not. However, regarding InteractiveServer, would you say it's normal to have an InteractiveServer as a frontend that makes request through SignalR? not browser. which means handling the cookies will need to be done manually right.
For example, manually adding cookies in the subsequent request. And also do you want me to share my progress code here for further reference?

What resources are you accessing and how?  With Server, you access the backend directly from the server code, there's no authentication per request.  All the C# code runs in the Hub session on the server.

Apparently, the answer to my problem is on the [Authorize] tag itself. Instead of using the tag itself, I used
<AuthorizedView>
 <Authorize>
 </Authorize>
<AuthorizedView>

This method did solve the issue I was having trouble with for the next step after login. Thanks for contributing
